# I need to modify a VBA code to delete all the other rows but not the one that I input

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA code

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim DeleteRng As Range
Dim DeleteStr As String
xTitleId = "Delete"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", xTitleId, Type:=2)
For Each rng In InputRng
    If rng.Value = DeleteStr Then
        If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteRng = rng
        Else
            Set DeleteRng = Application.Union(DeleteRng, rng)
        End If
    End If
Next
DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

This one deletes all the rows for the word I input. I need it to delete all the others except the word I input.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just change `If rng.Value = DeleteStr Then` to `If rng.Value <> DeleteStr Then`.

Comment: That's what I did in the first place and it just deletes everything. It's not working like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you allow the user to select a range of more than one column.  With `If rng.Value <> DeleteStr Then` if the search string exist in one cell of a selected row but not in another cell on the same row, that row is marked for deletion.

So, consider each row seperately.  If any cell in that row equals the search string, exclude the row from from deletion

Something like this

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range
    Dim delRow As Boolean
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim DeleteRng As Range
    Dim DeleteStr As String
    Dim xTitleId As String

    xTitleId = "Delete"
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", xTitleId, Type:=2)
    For Each rw In InputRng.Rows
        delRow = True
        For Each rng In rw.Cells
            If rng.Value = DeleteStr Then
                delRow = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If delRow Then
            If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteRng = rw.EntireRow
            Else
                Set DeleteRng = Application.Union(DeleteRng, rw.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
        DeleteRng.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is sub-optimal as it loops through rows.

A quicker version would use `COUNTIF` to check if your non-delete condition was met by the row, then you could use an `AutoFilter` to delete the rows where the condition is not found.

So you could do this manually or with VBA.

If you data was in columns B:D this code inserts the working formula in a new column, then deletes the rows where the condition is true.

`=COUNTIF(B2:D2,"Your Condition" )>0`

*code*

```
Sub Quicker()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim DeleteStr As String
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", "Delete", , , , , , 2)

With rng1.Columns(1).Offset(0, rng1.Columns.Count)
     .EntireColumn.Insert
     .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(RC[-" & rng1.Columns.Count + 1 & "]:RC[-2],""" & DeleteStr & """ )>0"
     .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="FALSE"
     'preserve header row    
     .Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
      On Error Resume Next
     .EntireColumn.Delete
     On Error GoTo 0
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job. You had the `EntireRow` in the wrong place.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    ' 03 Apr 2017

    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim DeleteRng As Range
    Dim DeleteStr As String
    Dim xTitleId As String

    xTitleId = "Delete"
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    DeleteStr = InputBox("Delete Text", xTitleId)
    For Each Cell In InputRng
        If StrComp(Cell.Value, DeleteStr, vbTextCompare) Then
            If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteRng = Cell.EntireRow
            Else
                Set DeleteRng = Application.Union(DeleteRng, Cell.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    DeleteRng.Delete
End Sub
```